# WSO2 ESB performance error

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I use WSO2 ESB 4.7.0 and WSO2 BAM 2.4.0. And I use same server for them. when I made loading test for 200 concurrent thread, ESB unreachable state.

I use http-nio

```
<transportReceiver name="http" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.HttpCoreNIOListener">
        <parameter name="port" locked="false">8280</parameter>
        <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="httpGetProcessor" locked="false">org.wso2.carbon.transport.nhttp.api.NHttpGetProcessor</parameter>
       </transportReceiver>
```

for ESB Level Performance settings

```
# HTTP Sender thread pool parameters
snd_t_core=450
snd_t_max=500
snd_alive_sec=5
snd_qlen=-1
snd_io_threads=4

# HTTP Listener thread pool parameters
lst_t_core=450
lst_t_max=500
lst_alive_sec=5
lst_qlen=-1
lst_io_threads=4
```

is there a problem performance settings? or problem OS Level?

Comment: Any reason for switching to http-nio? When you mean "same server", I suppose you run both ESB and BAM with different offsets. Do you see any errors in the ESB or BAM consoles?

Comment: There was an issue with data agent. https://wso2.org/jira/browse/BAMDATAAGENTS-9 This should be fixed in ESB 4.8.1. Please let us know whether you encountered a similar issue.

Comment: Hello Isuru. Thank you for interest. Yes, I run both ESB and BAM with different offsets. I dont see (repository/logs). I can not use 4.8.1 because I can not use "BAM Service Data Agent Aggregate" for 4.8.1. And I need it.